# Undefined reference to `__gmpz and makefile

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, undefined

I can’t figure out why I’m getting these compilation errors:

```
gcc -o Compil obj/MillerRabin.o obj/main.o -L. -L/usr/lib/ -Wl,-rpath=/home/---------/Documents/AC20_Cyrpto -lgmp  -lCommon  -ltest  -lprimeGen
./libtest.so: undefined reference to `__gmpz_set_str'
./libtest.so: undefined reference to `__gmpz_set_ui'
./libtest.so: undefined reference to `__gmpz_add_ui'
./libtest.so: undefined reference to `__gmpz_clear'
./libtest.so: undefined reference to `__gmpz_init'
./libtest.so: undefined reference to `mpzPrint'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:61: recipe for target 'Compil' failed
make: *** [Compil] Error 1
```

These errors are coming from `libs/test/test.c`, I’m using a make file that a friend of mine made, and I haven’t really looked into how they work yet.

So what’s weird is that in my libs folder I have another **.c** file that’s using gmp (`libs/Common/common.h` and `mpzfunctions.c`), and that one doesn’t give me any errors. If I move my test function to the main the compilation works.

If anyone knows how to fix this, it would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbols from libraries are applied in order. So when you write:

```
-lgmp -ltest
```

It means that symbols used in libgmp will be looked up in libtest but not vice versa.

Apparently, your libtest requires functions from libgmp, so you need to apply them in the opposite order.

As a rule of thumb, external libraries should always go last because they do not generally require symbols from your libraries.

So without knowing too much, I 'd guess that the order should  be:

```
 -lCommon -lprimeGen -ltest -lgmp
```

It looks to me like you will want to remove `-lgmp` from `LINK_FLAGS` and add it somehow to the end of the link command.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I’m going to see how I can do that though I don’t have a lot of experience in working with make files.

Comment: @Gambon: This one doesn't look too awful. A quick and dirty fix would be to remove `-lgmp` from where it is in the definition of LINK_FLAGS and add it to the end of the definition of LIBS_LINK (with a space before it)

Comment: So that fixed part of the problem, gmp isn’t giving me any errors, but I still have that last one with the mpzPrint function I wrote.

Comment: @gambon: it is probably the same issue, but you'll have to figure out where it is. Which library/ies is the function used in? Which lbrary is it defined in? Remember: in the link command, definitions are only looked up for symbols which have already been mentioned.

Comment: Symbol dependencies between libraries is often annoying, and generally makes it difficult to automate building lists of `-l` options. I would just define `LIBS_LINK` by hand instead of trying to be clever; you'll have to change it if you add another library to the project, but it does let you adjust the order as necessary. (The usual name for this variablevis `LDLIBS`, by the way. But there's no rule about that.)

Comment: mpzPrint is defined in common.h, and right now it’s only used in test.c. So I manually changed the order so that is looks like this: LIBS_LINK= -lprimeGen -ltest -lCommon –lgmp, and it seems to have fixed it! 
I’m going to have to see how LIBS_LINK=$(patsubst $(LIBS_DIR)%, -l%,$(LIBS)) actually works, theres probably a way to make it work without having to manually enter each library. Anyways thanks for the help!
Edit: Didn't see your second message, but I was able to figure it out, Thanks again!

Comment: You'll get into this type of error even if there are unmet dependencies. I had the OP issue but the fix was some missing depends.